Is there any significance in the way Hollies are described in Narnia?
Among the various types of trees listed in Prince Caspian when Aslan is waking the dryads and the trees are coming to life, I noticed in particular the description of the hollies:

What Lucy and Susan saw was a dark something coming to them from almost every direction across the hills. It looked first like a black mist creeping on the ground, then like the stormy waves of a black sea rising higher and higher as it came on, and then, at last, like what it was—woods on the move. All the trees of the world appeared to be rushing towards Aslan. But as they drew nearer they looked less like trees, and when the whole crowd, bowing and curtsying and waving thin long arms to Aslan, were all around Lucy, she saw that it was a crowd of human shapes. Pale birch-girls were tossing their heads, willow-women pushed back their hair from their brooding faces to gaze on Aslan, the queenly beeches stood still and adored him, shaggy oak-men, lean and melancholy elms, shock-headed hollies (dark themselves, but their wives all bright with berries) and gay rowans, all bowed and rose again, shouting, "Aslan, Aslan!" in their various husky or creaking or wave-like voices.

(emphasis mine in all quotes)
And later, at the feast after the battle was won, the trees eat what is essentially earth:

But for the tree people different fare was provided. When Lucy saw Clodsley Shovel and his moles scuffling up the turf in various places (which Bacchus had pointed out to them) and realised that the trees were going to eat earth it gave her rather a shudder. But when she saw the earths that were actually brought to them she felt quite different. They began with a rich brown loam that looked almost exactly like chocolate; so like chocolate, in fact, that Edmund tried a piece of it, but he did not find it at all nice. When the rich loam had taken the edge off their hunger, the trees turned to an earth of the kind you see in Somerset, which is almost pink. They said it was lighter and sweeter. At the cheese stage they had a chalky soil, and then went on to delicate confections of the finest gravels powdered with choice silver sand. They drank very little wine, and it made the Hollies very talkative: for the most part they quenched their thirst with deep draughts of mingled dew and rain, flavoured with forest flowers and the airy taste of the thinnest clouds.

Is there any significance to the way that hollies, in particular, are portrayed? Why are the males described as dark with only their wives bearing berries? Why are they in particular, rather than any other trees, described as talkative under the influence of wine? Does this tie into anything about the symbolism of plants?

It is at least biologically true that there are male and female hollies, with only the latter having berries.

And holly leaves are a fairly dark green (at least the ones near the house I grew up in). Darker than most other tree leaves.

Some plants are dioecious - male and female flowers are produced by different individuals. Holly is one of them - a female tree will only have berries if it has received pollen from a nearby male tree. Holly leaves are typically dark green (though there are variegated forms).
I can't suggest why the hollies in particular are described as talkative.
